# parsing error with android app

Tags: android

I know this has been asked before, but nothing is working.

I have signed my app.

I sent the signed apk as an email attachment.

I click on the email attachment to install it and I get a parsing error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks 
DeanO

screen shot link  http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/EAdwMYNAPXSoY9BU8VJRhw?feat=directlink

Comment: can you show us the error you've faced in detail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears to be something with emailing the apk file or something on the one persons phone.  So not sure on this one.  It appears each phone even though it may use android 2.1 or 2.2 supports different functionality of the 2.1 or 2.2 spec.  I am calling this one closed.  Thanks to all those who replied.